# Digital Rights Management in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, drm

I have a NetStream set up and it's supposed to listen for DRMAuthenticateEvent.DRM_Authenticate.  When I give it an encrypted file (encrypted using software from drm-x.com), no DRMAuthenticateEvenet seems to be dispatched.  The code looks like this:

```
    private function init():void
{
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

ns = new NetStream(nc);
ns.addEventListener(DRMAuthenticateEvent.DRM_AUTHENTICATE, DRMAuthHandler);
ns.play("phone_P.flv");
video = new Video();
video.attachNetStream(ns);
...}
```

I am trying to use the setDRMAuthenticationCredentials function as follows:

```
private function DRMAuthHandler(event:DRMAuthenticationEvent):void
{
ns.setDRMAuthenticationCredentials("testuser", "test", "proxy");
ns.setDRMAuthenticationCredentials("testuser", "test", "drm");
label2.text = "authentication event dispatched!";          //for debugging
}
```

I have both proxy and drm authentication types in there because drm was not working for me so I decided to try proxy.
Am I doing something wrong? I got this stuff off of the Adobe reference pages, is there an easier/smarter way of going about DRM in Flex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When using DRM in Flex (and more specifically AIR) you have to use Flash Digital Rights Management Server. That's the only system that is supported for DRM in AIR.